# How override a material-ui variable or function

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material-UI  component.
This one from git : https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/pages/components/tabs/ScrollableTabsButtonAuto.js

My main problem is when i use the scroll button, that scroll too much ( i have lot of tabs, something like 20 tabs ). So when i click on scroll button, that scroll to the right a lot and i lose my active tab.

I have tried to check the code of Tabs.
I found the 2 function i have to override.
These functions are inside that js code:
https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/Tabs/Tabs.js

```
  var handleStartScrollClick = function handleStartScrollClick() {
    moveTabsScroll(-tabsRef.current[clientSize]);
  };

  var handleEndScrollClick = function handleEndScrollClick() {
    moveTabsScroll(tabsRef.current[clientSize]);
  };
```

If i modify it on node_modules directy that work well, here an exemple :

```
  var handleStartScrollClick = function handleStartScrollClick() {
    moveTabsScroll(-tabsRef.current[clientSize]/10);
  };

  var handleEndScrollClick = function handleEndScrollClick() {
    moveTabsScroll(tabsRef.current[clientSize]/10);
  };
```

So now when i click on scroll button i have good result, it's scrolling step by step. But i can't directly overide into node_modules.
How can i do to do it correctly & properly please ?

Comment: There isn't any easy way to customize this, but I don't understand why you want to. The intent of the scroll is to see the next set of tabs that are currently not visible. Particularly if there are a lot of tabs, your change seems a lot worse for the user. If the user wants to get to the last tab out of 20 tabs, the user will have to click the scroll button many times. If five tabs fit on the screen at once, then the default would allow the user to get to the last 5 tabs (of 20) in 3 clicks, but with your change it would take 30 clicks to get to the last tab.

Comment: @RyanCogswell
That it, you understand ;) 
And yes i agree with you, but our Product Owner ask me this because client want this :) You know.... developer life haha